# Build gradle kotlin dsl task extension method

Tags: build.gradle, kotlin-dsl

I want to modify my `build.gradle.kts` by implementing some tasks. Specially, I want to obtain the output of the first task in my second task, where the first task runs a shell command. There are some basic examples [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) and [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/command-line-task/7280/5), which are implemented in groovy dsl. Now, I need this functionality in kotlin dsl.

A working example is:

```
task<Exec>("avdIsRunning") {
        commandLine("adb", "devices")
        standardOutput = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    
}
task("task2") {
    dependsOn("avdIsRunning")
      doLast {
        val standardOutput = (tasks.getByName("avdIsRunning") as Exec).standardOutput.toString()
        println("Foo's output: $standardOutput")
      }
  }
```

What I want is, to call a extension method `avdIsRunning.output()` that provides the standradOutput of avdIsRunning-task, compare to the examples I linked above.